# GridView sorting problem?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

after i sort my gridview, when i want to edit a row the selected row is completely wrong.

what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

After sorting, try setting the SelectedIndex property to -1.

Alternatively, try using the SelectedDataKey property (check [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1213602.aspx) for details).  Note that you may have to write your code in the PreRender event for the data keys to be set.

Comment: In a few forums, it's mentioned about datarowbound to fix this problem, but i can't figured out why